# How do I make image visible when collection view cell is double tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, touch, gesture

I have a collection view with a lot of images and all of these images has a heart image in the right corner. This heart image needs to be set to visible when the big image is double tapped as an indicator that it has been liked.

I have added a double tap gesture to my collection view and now I need to set the heart image to visible when this gesture happens on the selected cell.

Any suggestions to how I do it? I can't find any answers to this anywhere.

This is my collection view controller:

```
import UIKit

class OevelserCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var OevelserCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer!

    var oevelseCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!

    let oevelseArray = OevelseArray()

    // MARK: - Init

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupOevelseCollectionView()

    }

    // MARK: - Functions

    @IBAction func didDoubleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tapped")

    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        setupOevelseCollectionViewItemSize()
    }

    private func setupOevelseCollectionView() {
        self.OevelserCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.OevelserCollectionView.dataSource = self
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "OevelseCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        OevelserCollectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "OevelseCollectionViewCell")
    }

    private func setupOevelseCollectionViewItemSize() {
        if oevelseCollectionViewFlowLayout == nil {
            let numberOfItemPerRow: CGFloat = 1
            let lineSpacing: CGFloat = 20
            let interItemSpacing: CGFloat = 8

            let width = (OevelserCollectionView.frame.width - (numberOfItemPerRow - 1) * interItemSpacing) / numberOfItemPerRow
            let height = width - 50

            oevelseCollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

            oevelseCollectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
            oevelseCollectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
            oevelseCollectionViewFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            oevelseCollectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = lineSpacing
            oevelseCollectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = interItemSpacing

        OevelserCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(oevelseCollectionViewFlowLayout, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return oevelseArray.oevelser.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OevelseCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OevelseCollectionViewCell

        let oevelseText = oevelseArray.oevelser[indexPath.item].oevelseName
        let oevelseImage = oevelseArray.oevelser[indexPath.item].oevelseImage
        cell.oevelseLabel.text = oevelseText
        cell.oevelseImageView.image = UIImage(named: oevelseImage)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}
```

And here is my collection view cell class:

```
import UIKit

class OevelseCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var oevelseImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var oevelseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var isLikedImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var heartImageWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `cellForRowAt`

```
    cell.oevelseImageView.image = UIImage(named: oevelseImage)
    cell.oevelseImageView.tag = indexPath.row
    let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)) 
    tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    cell.oevelseImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)
```

---

```
@objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
   let index = gesture.view!.tag
   guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:IndexPath(row:index,section:0)) else { return }
   arr[index].isLiked.toggle()
   cell.isLikedImageView.image = arr[index].isLiked ? <#likeImg#> : <#defImg#>
}
```

OR

```
@objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){ 
    arr[gesture.view!.tag ].isLiked.toggle() 
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at:[IndexPath(row:index,section:0)],with:.none)
}
```

Comment: I would like to set the isLikedImageView.isHidden to false when the tap happens. I tried this: 
```@objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let index = gesture.view!.tag
        oevelseArray.oevelser[index].isLiked.toggle()
        if (oevelseArray.oevelser[index].isLiked == true) {
            cell.isLikedImageView.isHidden = false
        }
    }```

And got the error: Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'